# how to remove 8080 from URL

Tags: url, jboss, localhost, port

Could someone please tell me, what can I do to give my application a simple URL. Right now I call my app with this URL -

```
http://localhostname:8080/MyProject
```

I would like to call it with this URL -

```
http://localhostname/MyProject
```

I'am using JBoss 7.1.0 Final version

Comment: Use port 80, the default one for HTTP.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossOnPort80

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.I'm trying

Comment: Defualt 80 port is used another application.

Comment: You can run only one application on port 80. Stop the another app using port 80. Do you run Apache web server on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

As said above in Alexander Pavlov's comments the easiest way to go about this is using port `80`.

Applications servers normally have a config file (usually xml) in which you specify the port for your application to use.  The default for most application servers is port `8080` so your url will look like this: `http://<server IP or name>:8080`.

If you modify your applications server configuration to make the default port `80` then you will only have to do this: `http://<server IP or Name>`

Answer (score 0):

I was in the process of researching this very topic (for a single instance though) and came across a recommendation from the RedHat Discussions.

This is Linux specific for a single instance. OP didn't specify environment. But this should point OP down the right path if using Linux.

Using port 80 & 443 requires root to run the JBoss instance. Chances are, the SA isn't going to grant this to the user, so an alternative is to have the SA modify the iptables. Credit goes to PixelDrift.NET Support over in the [RedHat Discussions](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/734233) for the great lead.

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
```

My SA modified the iptables to our needs.

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8380 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9990 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 9443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8380
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
```

After the changes were applied, I was successfully able to access the application using `http://bar.foo/baz` without the necessity of including the port number.